# Don't know how to use navigation.navigate in React Native app

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, navigation

I created a basic `SplashScreen.tsx` that just has some text on it. Then, I created this `LoginCreateAccountScreen.tsx`, which has a Login button and Create Account button. I want my app to show the `SplashScreen.tsx` for a few seconds before it automatically navigates to `LoginCreateAccountScreen.tsx`. Also, pressing the buttons should redirect the user to other screens, but that also does not work. I don't know how to do this and have had a lot of difficulties figuring out exactly how to accomplish this.

I used this [React Native Navigation Article](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation) as well as [This Tutorial](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html) to get to where I am right now, along with various StackOverflow posts. But to be honest, I am pretty lost as there is just so much going on with regards to frontend navigation.

I don't understand how `AppNavigator.js` and `App.js` (the entry point for my app) work in conjunction to let me be able to navigate to another screen from my current screen. Right now, I can't get any kind of navigation working. I have to manually change the screen by setting it in `App.js`.

My `App.js`, which renders the SplashScreen. But won't transition to the LoginCreateAccountScreen.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import EmojiDict from './screens/EmojiDict';
import SplashScreen from './screens/SplashScreen';
import LoginCreateAccountScreen from './screens/LoginCreateAccountScreen'

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return <SplashScreen />;
    }
}
```

My `AppNavigator.js`:

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import MainTabNavigator from "./MainTabNavigator";
import { Platform } from "react-native";
// Importing my screens here.
import LoginCreateAccountScreen from "../screens/LoginCreateAccountScreen";
import CreateAccountScreen from "../screens/CreateAccountScreen";
import LoginScreen from "../screens/Login/LoginScreen";
import SplashScreen from "../screens/SplashScreen";

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  SplashScreen: {screen: SplashScreen},
  LoginCreateAccountScreen: {screen: LoginCreateAccountScreen},
  LoginScreen: {screen: LoginScreen},
  CreateAccountScreen: {screen: CreateAccountScreen},
});

const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default App;
```

My `SplashScreen.tsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';

class SplashScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>
                    The Good App
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 45,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
});

export default SplashScreen;
```

My `LoginCreateAccountScreen.tsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  Text,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

function Separator() {
  return <View style={styles.separator} />;
}

class CreateAccountOrLogin extends Component {
    handleLogInButton = () => {
        Alert.alert('Log In pressed')
        this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen");
    };

    handleCreateAccountButton = () => {
        Alert.alert('Create Account pressed')
        this.props.navigation.navigate("CreateAccountScreen");
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.customButtonBackground}
                onPress={() => this.handleLogInButton()}>
                    <Text style={styles.customButtonText}>Login</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.customButtonBackground}
                onPress={() => this.handleCreateAccountButton()}>
                    <Text style={styles.customButtonText}>Create Account</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    /* Here, style the text of your button */
    customButtonText: {
        fontSize: 35,
        fontWeight: '400',
        color: "#fff",
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    /* Here, style the background of your button */
    customButtonBackground: {
        backgroundColor: "#007aff",
        paddingHorizontal: 30,
        paddingVertical: 5,
        borderRadius: 30,
        width: "70%",
        aspectRatio: 5 / 1,
    }
});

export default CreateAccountOrLogin;
```

I get the following error when I press on the Login or Create Account button, which is the same for both:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where react navigation is useful. Ill guide you with this. I believe you have installed react navigation as per the docs. Otherwise make sure to download that first. Check this [react-navigatoin-doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html) . Hope it helps.

So let's start with the stack navigator first, So you want to show splashscreen at start and then navigate to loginscreen right. So AppNavigator should look like this :

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import MainTabNavigator from "./MainTabNavigator";
import { Platform } from "react-native";
// Importing my screens here.
import LoginCreateAccountScreen from "../screens/LoginCreateAccountScreen";
import CreateAccountScreen from "../screens/CreateAccountScreen";
import LoginScreen from "../screens/Login/LoginScreen";
import SplashScreen from "../screens/SplashScreen";

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  SplashScreen: {screen: SplashScreen},
  LoginCreateAccountScreen: {screen: LoginCreateAccountScreen},
  LoginScreen: {screen: LoginScreen},
  CreateAccountScreen: {screen: CreateAccountScreen},
},
{ initialRouteName: 'SplashScreen'} // have added this coz you want splashscreen to be first rendered
);

const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default App;
```

So now that your app navigator has been made, now lets switch to splash screen where you want it to be rendered for suppose 3 secs and then navigate it to LoginScreen. So we will redirect to login screen in componentDidMount , lets build that one.

Splashscreen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';

class SplashScreen extends Component {

componentDidMount(){

this.setTimeout(() => {this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen")} , 3000); // im redirecting to login screen after 3 secs of showing splash screen.
}

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>
                    The Good App
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 45,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
});

export default SplashScreen;
```

And after that , in login screen you can redirect the user from login to any screen  by `this.props.navigation.navigate("ScreenName")` , just make sure you add your screen in the AppNavigator before doing the above code, like first

```
import ScreenName from "../screens/ScreenName";

    const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      SplashScreen: {screen: SplashScreen},
      LoginCreateAccountScreen: {screen: LoginCreateAccountScreen},
      LoginScreen: {screen: LoginScreen},
      CreateAccountScreen: {screen: CreateAccountScreen},
     ScreenName:{screen:ScreenName}
    },
    { initialRouteName: 'SplashScreen'} // have added this coz you want splashscreen to be first rendered
    );
```

then only `this.props.navigation.navigate("ScreenName")` this would work.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Hi, this makes total sense to me. However, my entry point for my app is `App.js`. I  am assuming I must import `AppNavigator` into `App.js` and render it?

Comment: you can write the appnavigator code inside the app.js if you dont have any other specific things going on in app.js , just paste your code in app.js

Answer (score 0):

Error message says, "There is no navigation props in your　Create Account Login component."

You need to add CreateAccountOrLogin to createStackNavigator, then createStackNavigator pass navigation props to CreateAccountOrLogin.

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  SplashScreen: {screen: SplashScreen},
  LoginCreateAccountScreen: {screen: LoginCreateAccountScreen},
  LoginScreen: {screen: LoginScreen},
  CreateAccountScreen: {screen: CreateAccountScreen},
+ CreateAccountOrLogin
});
```

Just write below code in CreateAccountOrLogin to know whether props.navigation is exist.

```
render() {
  console.log(this.props) 
  return(
```